# 128 bit key AES encrypting application in java

Tags: java, aes

i need to create an application in java that would convert text strings into codes based on 128bit AES encryption.. ideally i would prefer that i only need to create a gui and the AES encryption part is already written. the application is need to be run in both linux and windows . kindly advice me on existing libraries and anything related. i am not an expert programmer so im asking this advice to gain confidence on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get your started... http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html

EDIT

Looks like http:// 192 . 9 . 162 . 55/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html could be an working link...

How do you posts IP addresses?

Comment: Any chance of getting this link updated to the same article on the Oracle website?

Answer (score 2):

In case it's useful, I put some stuff on the web about [AES encryption in Java](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/symmetric.shtml), including example encryption/decryption code (actually, the code is essentially similar for other algorithms).

Things that typically trip people up:

- if you're generating random keys (well, actually in any case, random or not), you need to do it appropriately (see the [SecureRandom](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/securerandom.shtml) class, for example)
- the basic encryption works on arrays of bytes; when converting strings to and from bytes (the String.getBytes() method and the String constructor that takes a byte array), you need to pick a character encoding that will preserve all the characters you will use (if you're not sure, probably start with "UTF-8")
- by default, the AES Cipher actually runs in a mode that is insecure (though if this is a homework project it might not matter); read up on [block modes](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/block_modes.shtml) for more informtation.